# Deleting a specific sub directory under all directories

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have several tests in a directory which were compiled in C and created the image or output in 'unmanaged' folders under each test directory. I would like to delete only the unmanaged folders under every test directory (a cleanup you can say) and keep all other directories like src, cmm, scf (scatter files) etc. unchanged.

I can do this either in Windows or Linux since the directory is mapped to Windows. Please let me know how do I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name unmanaged -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```